# Get page status code from "domcontentloaded" event

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, http-status-codes

I am currently trying to get the response code (eg. 200, 404, 403, ...) after the domcontentloaded event in puppeteer is fired. I am not able to use the response from .goto(...) since my application gets redirected multiple times while running by clicking links etc. Is there any way to get the status code of a page only using the page object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions) instead of `page.goto` as they both return a promise which resolves to the main resource response. It also has the `waitUntil` option, so you are able to check the `domcontentloaded` event. With `waitForNavigation` :

> In case of multiple redirects, the navigation will resolve with the response of the last redirect.

You can use it like this:

```js
await page.goto('https://www.google.com', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })

// navigation
await page.waitForSelector('input[name="btnI"]')
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('input[name="btnI"]').click())

// get response
const response = await page.waitForNavigation()
console.log(response.status())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This definitely got me pointed the right way. I am sadly not able to use this exact implementation because the page is going to navigate in unknown interval. I somehow need to get a event which is fired once the browser naviagates to a nother page. And get the status of this. This navigation may happen after 5 seconds, after 20 minutes or sometimes never.